# What's the best iPhone model for App Design

Tags: interface-design

I am planning to buy an iPhone as a test rig for app design, to see the designs on the device.

If I can only afford one, what is the best iPhone model to be use for mobile app design previewing?

iPhone 5/5S/5SE (4 inch, 640x1136 pixels)

iPhone 6/6S (4.7 inch, 750x1334 pixels)

iPhone 6/S Plus (5.5 inch, 1080x1920 scaled pixels)

Comment: I don't really understand the question. If you're designing apps for the iPhone you should be designing for *all* models.

Comment: i mean what is the best iPhone model for viewing the design output from photoshop, iPhone 5s or 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you are in the world, pick up a second hand iPod Touch 5th Generation, for the 640x1136 of the iPhone 5, 5S and 5SE testing. This is the same screen size, and the cheapest way to get at this screen size.

These 5th Gen iPod Touches have the worst colour reproduction of all current iOS devices, so if what you make looks good on this, you're going to be fine on the others. This is actually more important than I previously thought it was. Some colours get completely lost on the lesser screens.

// iPad mini 2 and 3 have the next worst colour reproduction on iOS devices. Absolute worst is iPod Touch 4th Generation, but its size is probably not pertinent anymore.

And, with whatever money you have left over, get the iPhone 6 Plus or 6S Plus with the 1920x1080 screen. This screen is difficult to test on your Mac/PC because the pixel density is much higher than your computer will likely have, and the one you really need a device to do proper design testing on because of this. This is particularly true if you're working in portrait, as very few computer screens can even show all the pixels 1:1... and then there's the fact Apple is downsizing, too...

You can sort of sense how the iPhone 6 is from working on the iPod Touch and within the Simulator or onscreen on your PC/Mac. It's not a radical difference. The Plus sized screens are very different.

Alternatively, many cheap Android phones have 1920x1080 screens, but different colour reproduction, so you could do design testing on one of these if you can get one super cheap, second hand. (Don't buy new, waste of money)... then get a 6 or 6S, since no Android devices have its unique 750x1334 resolution. But keep in mind the colour differences could be extreme between cheap Android devices and the iPhone 6/S Plus.

Comment: great thanks! so i should buy and iphone 5s or ipod touch 5th gen :D